# Force Android canvas to be on top of bitmap used for Google Maps markers

Tags: android, google-maps, canvas, google-maps-api-3, bitmap

I'm drawing a circle with some text on top of a bitmap, and then using the bitmap as the icon for a Google Maps marker/pin.

Most of the time, it works perfectly, but *sometimes* the circle+text will show up BEHIND the bitmap - not good. It seems to consistently happen if i navigate to a new activity, and then go back.

Code:

```
// Make room for the circle
Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstWidth, dstHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
int xMatrix = xPadding / 2;
matrix.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()), new RectF(xMatrix,yPadding, dstWidth - xMatrix, dstHeight), Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
canvas.drawCircle(xPos, yPos, 30, backgroundPaint);
if(_badge != null && _badge.equalsIgnoreCase("") == false) {
    canvas.drawText(_badge, xPos, yPos+10, textPaint);
}
return myBitmap;
```

Is there a way i can force my circle+text to be on top? Perhaps i should try to make my bitmap immutable (how do i do this?)

Answer (score 0):

**Identifying the issue:**
It's seems that you "don't clean after finishing your work".

What is that mean?: You are correctly showing circle and text on the top.

But after close *activity/fragment* and reopen the map you get weird result because of  drawing new `canvas` above last one. And you're doing that every time you open the `map` so it will be more weird of you navigated from map fragment much times.

**Why that happened?:**

Having multiple views (old canvas + old text and circle plus news of them) do that.

**Solution:**

Clear what you have made!.

One of the easiest ways is to clear your map in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` : `mMap.clear()`.

Other way: Is to draw canvas and objects only if needed.